# Driving Mode isn't working as expected on Samsung Galaxy SII

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, car-dock

I have this Samsung Galaxy SII, GT-I9100T, with Android version 2.3.3.

When placed in Dock with my car, the following happens

- Whenever a call is incoming, the phone would read me the calling number, even if he's found in my contacts.
- Whenever a message is incoming, the phone will **sometimes** read me their phone number, even if they're found in my contacts.

What can cause this? I've checked the configuration and found nothing helpful, Google wasn't much of a help either.

Comment: @liamwli Why have you removed the text-to-speech tag? Is it not related?

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the contacts have been entered incorrectly, or it could be a bug with your version of the car mode app.

Please ensure that none of your contacts are duplicated, and also please ensure that the numbers are correct (you may need to add/remove the country code).

Another reason could be due to the country code being displayed when the SMS/Call is incoming, but not being in the contact.

Comment: Thing is, the number is read correctly (without country code): "Incoming call from zero-five-two-eight-five-eight-eight....", while it should say "Incoming call from Madara Uchiha" for that instance. There may be duplication, but they are linked, does that make a difference?